# How submit captcha to the controller using ajax and form data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, captcha

I have a `form` with some fields and file upload, rendering as a `partial view` using `ajax` in `asp.net MVC`. when submitting the form, I want to pass all the data to the controller. But if I use `$("form").serialize()`, it is not passing the selected file to the controller. So I am using `formData()` to pass the data to the controller. Till this point, everything works fine.

But after adding `captcha` using `CaptchaMvc`, it not reaching the controller. Even if I enter valid `captcha`, it is invalid in the controller.

This is how I send data to the controller using the `ajax` and `formData`

```
       var data = new FormData(); 
        var vidFile = null;
        if ($("#FileUpload")[0].files.length > 0)
            vidFile = $("#FileUpload")[0].files[0];
        data.append("detail", $("#detail").val());
        data.append("name", $("#name").val());

        data.append("FileUpload", vidFile);
       $.ajax({
            url: "/home/submitData",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.success == true) {


                } else {

                }
            }
        });
```

Is there any way to pass the captcha as well to the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you validate using different controller function, as follows:

At the time of submission, validate the captcha first, and depending on the result, call another controller function to submit data or show the error.

```
 var submitData = function(){
    var data = new FormData(); 
    var vidFile = null;
    if ($("#FileUpload")[0].files.length > 0)
       vidFile = $("#FileUpload")[0].files[0];
    data.append("detail", $("#detail").val());
    data.append("name", $("#name").val());
    data.append("FileUpload", vidFile);
    $.ajax({
       url: "/home/submitData",
       type: "POST",
       contentType: false,
       processData:false,
       data: data,
       success: function (response) {
          if (response.success == true) {
            //Success

          } else {
               //Submission failed
          }
      }
   });
}
var validateCaptcha = function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "/home/validateCaptcha",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
      success: function (response) {
          if (response.success == true) {
             submitData();
          } else {
             alert("Invalid Captcha entry");
          }
      }
 });
}
$("form").submit(function(e){
   validateCaptcha();
});
```